# Gnuplot grid format xtics mxtics

Tags: gnuplot

How can I define one format for the main grid (xtics, ytics) and another one for the minor tics (mxtics and mytics)?

I tried:

```
set style line 100 lt 1 lc rgb "gray" lw 2
set style line 101 lt 1 lc rgb "gray" lw 1
set grid xtics ytics ls 100
set grid mxtics mytics ls 101
```

But this take the last defined lw (1) for all grids.

Comment: This is a little confusing because the grid is only drawn at the major tic marks.

Answer (score 11):

```
set style line 100 lt 1 lc rgb "gray" lw 2
set style line 101 lt 0.5 lc rgb "gray" lw 1

set grid mytics ytics ls 100, ls 101
set grid mxtics xtics ls 100, ls 101
```

It really works :).

Answer (score 6):

The minor tics mxtics and mytics are also drawn but with the same format than the main tics. And that is a problem when you want to differentiate them. Your solution with the arrows did the trick but I found it easier to first draw the minor ticks and than overwrite them with arrows for the main ones. Tanks.

```
set style line 100 lt 2 lc rgb "blue" lw 1
set style line 101 lt 1 lc rgb "gray" lw 1

# first draw the minor tics
set xrange [0:1]
set mxtics 10
set yrange [0:1]
set mytics 5
set grid mxtics mytics ls 101

# then the main tics
dx=0.2  #grid spacing in x
set for [i=1:5] arrow from graph i*dx,graph 0 to graph i*dx,graph 1 nohead front ls 100
dy=0.2  #grid spacing in y
set for [i=1:5] arrow from graph 0,graph i*dy to graph 1,graph i*dy nohead front ls 100

plot sin(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

`gnuplot` will also draw grid lines at minor tics using `set grid mxtics mytics`.

To set different line styles for major grid lines and minor grid lines, use the correct syntax (with a comma separating the major line style from the minor line style):

```
set style line 100 lt 1 lc rgb "blue" lw 2
set style line 101 lt 1 lc rgb "gray" lw 1
set grid mxtics mytics ls 100, ls 101
```

Answer (score 1):

In gnuplot, the grid is only drawn at the location of the major tic marks, however, if you want to have two distinct grids, you can use arrows:

```
set style line 101 lt 1 lc rgb "gray" lw 1
dx=.1  #grid spacing in x
set for [i=1:10] arrow from graph i*dx,graph 0 to graph i*dx,graph 1 nohead front ls 101 
set xrange [0:1]
plot sin(x)
```