# Adding grid in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I've the following script that runs fine in gnuplot (unfortunately I've an old version, and for now I can't do much about it, it's the 4.0).

```
set xlabel "y" 
set ylabel "rw[j]"
set title "P-D diagram"
set zeroaxis

set xzeroaxis
plot [0.5:1] \
-5.71429*x title "L[-5]" linetype 1, \
-4.28571*x title "U[-5]" linetype 3, \
-4.71429*x title "L[-4]" linetype 1, \
-3.28571*x title "U[-4]" linetype 3, \
-3.71429*x title "L[-3]" linetype 1, \
-2.28571*x title "U[-3]" linetype 3, \
-2.71429*x title "L[-2]" linetype 1, \
-1.28571*x title "U[-2]" linetype 3, \
-1.71429*x title "L[-1]" linetype 1, \
-0.285714*x title "U[-1]" linetype 3, \
-0.714286*x title "L[0]" linetype 1, \
0.714286*x title "U[0]" linetype 3, \
0.285714*x title "L[1]" linetype 1, \
1.71429*x title "U[1]" linetype 3, \
1.28571*x title "L[2]" linetype 1, \
2.71429*x title "U[2]" linetype 3, \
2.28571*x title "L[3]" linetype 1, \
3.71429*x title "U[3]" linetype 3, \
3.28571*x title "L[4]" linetype 1, \
4.71429*x title "U[4]" linetype 3, \
4.28571*x title "L[5]" linetype 1, \
5.71429*x title "U[5]" linetype 3
pause - 1
```

Below a picture (I know... it's quite bad but it doesn't matter for now...).
[image]

What I want to do is to add a kind of grid, if I use the `grid` command with `xticks`, `yticks` setting etc I get a grid however when I perform the zoom the grid isn't zoomed as well (I.e. it does depend from the window and not from the global coordinate system).

What I want to do is kind of setting lines for each `dy = 0.5` for example, similarly to `dx = 0.25`. This is because the spacing, and therefore the whole script, is derived using a small C++ program. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gnuplot grid format xtics mxtics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492903/gnuplot-grid-format-xtics-mxtics)

Answer (score 6):

The location of the grid lines are tied to the location of the (major and minor) tic marks. If you want to determine their spacing, you could try

```
set ytics 0.5
set grid y
```

If that is too many tic marks for your taste you can use minor marks instead:

```
set ytics 2
set mytics 4
set grid y my
```

At least this is how it works on somewhat recent versions of gnuplot (version 4.0 came out in 2004!).